# Error when creating a foreignkey in views.py in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I get the following error:

```
ValueError at /answer_question/
Cannot assign "'USERNAME_OF_MY_ACCOUNT_IN_DJANGO'": "Answer.author" must be a "Customer" instance.
```

when I make a new object in the database in Django.

views.py

```
def answer_question(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        path = request.GET.get('path')
        print(str(path))
        title = request.POST.get('answer-title-input')
        print(str(title))
        context = request.POST.get('answer-context-input')
        print(str(context))

        path=str(path)
        post=str(path[7:])
        print("POST = " + post)

        post = get_object_or_404(Post, title=post)
        print("POST FROM DATABASE = " + str(post))

        
        Answer.objects.create(
            title = title,
            context = context,
            date=("Date"),
            author = request.user.username,
            post = post,
        )

        return redirect(path)
```

The author should be the person who posted the answer.

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, help_text="Use this field for notes about the customer.")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = 'placeholder.png'
        return url

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    context = models.TextField(max_length=1702, blank=True, validators=[MaxLengthValidator(1702)])
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=date.today)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Answer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    context = models.TextField(max_length=1702, blank=True, validators=[MaxLengthValidator(1702)])
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=date.today)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

That means that a customer can for instance make a question: "How to do something" and another customer can answer on that post: "Here is a way to solve it". Just like Stack Overflow. There is a foreignkey linking a post to a customer. There is one on the answer class as well. They both have to have an author. 
What did I do wrong here?

```
author = request.user.username,
```

It should get the logged in user from the request and assigns it to the foreignkey.

Comment: author is foreign key to customer so it should be request.user.customer, and in no way .username as this is just a string and not user nor customer instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the customer object in creating answer:

```
Answer.objects.create(
    title = title,
    context = context,
    date=("Date"),
    author = request.user.customer,
    post = post,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

your Answer.author is ForeignKey to Customer, when you use request.user.username, that mean get username that id string not instance, not Customer, you can try this

```
customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
Answer.objects.create(title = title,
                      context = context,
                      date=("Date"),
                      author = customer,
                      post = post,)
```